# SSRS if condition for less than and equal to time

Tags: sql, time, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to make an expression that will show answered call if it received in less than or equal to 45 second.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this because I'm new to SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show if a call was answered in 45 seconds or less, you would use and **IIF** function to evaluate your field and determine whether to return the **TRUE** value or **FALSE** value.

The first argument of an IIF is the expression to be evaluated - in your case this would be with some Handle Time field that is usually in seconds (Fields!Handle_Time.Value <= 45). The second argument of the IIF would be what value to return if TRUE ("Yes"). The third arugment would be the FALSE value ("No").

Your expression would be something like

```
=IIF(Fields!Handle_Time.Value <= 45, "Yes", "No")
```

If you have a table and only want to show records where the Handle Time is less that 45 seconds, you should use a filter on the table. You would choose you Handle Time field for the Expression, change the Type to **Integer**, set the Operator to **<=** and put **45** in the Value box.